# spring security: two access denied pages/handlers depending on which resource was accessed

Tags: java, spring-security

For example, I have :

```
<intercept-url pattern="/aaa/**" access="ROLE_AAA" />
<intercept-url pattern="/bbb/**" access="ROLE_BBB" />
```

And, accordingly, if user wanted page /aaa and at the same time had no role ROLE_AAA - I want make him redirect to page /access-denied-aaa/

And, if he was trying to get /bbb and had no ROLE_BBB -> to page /access-denied-bbb/.

Currently I can describe only one AccessDeniedHandler, with a one common accessDenied page...

How it is normally can be implemented? preferably using the Spring Security

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always implement your own `AccessDeniedHandler`. Here's an example I made by extending the default [`AccessDeniedHandlerImpl`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/AccessDeniedHandlerImpl.html) (package and imports omitted):

```
public class PageByResourceAccessDeniedHandler extends AccessDeniedHandlerImpl {

    //~ Instance fields ===================================

    /**A Map of Path by Error Page*/
    private Map<String, String> errorPagesByPaths;
    /**The default error page if any of {@link #errorPagesByRole} matches */
    private String defaultErrorPage;

    //~ Main Methods ======================================

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException,
            ServletException {
        String errorPage = determineErrorPage(request);
        setErrorPage(errorPage);
        super.handle(request, response, accessDeniedException);
    }

    /**
     * Searches into the property {@link #errorPagesByRole} for a matching error page
     * for the current denied request path.
     * @param request current request
     * @return a matching error page found in {@link #errorPagesByRole} or {@link #defaultErrorPage}
     * if none was found.
     */
    private String determineErrorPage(HttpServletRequest request) {
        AntPathMatcher apm = new AntPathMatcher();

        for (String key : errorPagesByPaths.keySet()) {
            if(apm.match(key, request.getServletPath())) {
                return errorPagesByPaths.get(key);
            }
        }
        return defaultErrorPage;
    }

    //~ Getters/Setters/Utilities =========================

    public void setErrorPagesByPaths(Map<String, String> errorPagesByPaths) {
        for (String key : errorPagesByPaths.keySet()) {
            validateErrorPage(errorPagesByPaths.get(key));
        }
        this.errorPagesByPaths = errorPagesByPaths;
    }

    public void setDefaultErrorPage(String errorPage) {
        validateErrorPage(errorPage);
        this.defaultErrorPage = errorPage;
    }

    /**
     * Simple validator based on {@link AccessDeniedHandlerImpl#setErrorPage(String)}
     * code. Just verifies if the page doesn't starts with <tt>/</tt>.
     * 
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the errorPage doesn't starts with <tt>/</tt>.
     */
    private void validateErrorPage(String errorPage) {
        if ((errorPage != null) && !errorPage.startsWith("/")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("errorPage " + errorPage + " must begin with '/'");
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how you configure it in your application context configuration file:

```
<bean id="pbrADH" class="com.foo.PageByResourceAccessDeniedHandler">
  <property name="defaultErrorPage" value="/errorpagedefault.jsp" />
  <property name="errorPagesByPaths">
    <map>
      <entry key="/aaa/**" value="/errorpageaaa.jsp" />
      <entry key="/bbb/**" value="/errorpagebbb.jsp" />
    </map>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Don't forget to tell Spring Security to use it, in your `http` section:

```
...
<http auto-config="true">
    <access-denied-handler ref="pbrADH" />
    ...
</http>
```

First of all, remember: this is just an idea. It works, but it can be improved.

Basically it has a Map in which the keys are the protected resources, and the values are their error pages. And it has a default one.
It uses an [`AntPathMatcher`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html) to determine the error page for the current request so you can normally use ant paths. After it decides what is the error page, the class just call the [`handle`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/AccessDeniedHandlerImpl.html#handle%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,%20org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException%29) method of it's superclass (`AccessDeniedHandlerImpl`).

A better way to configure it would be something like:

```
<property name="errorPagesByRoles">
  <map>
    <entry key="ROLE_AAA" value="/errorpageaaa.jsp" />
    <entry key="ROLE_BBB" value="/errorpagebbb.jsp" />
  </map>
</property>
```

But I couldn't find a way to know what was the role the user didn't had that caused the error. If you look at the [`RoleVoter`](http://git.springsource.org/spring-security/spring-security/blobs/3.0.x/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/access/vote/RoleVoter.java#line94) code, you can see that this information is lost.